# Get property from derived class in base class

Tags: php, inheritance, properties, derived-class, base-class

base.php:

```
<?php namespace MyQuestion\Base;

abstract class BaseSetting
{
    public function GetValue($setting)
    {
        return $this->$setting;
    }
}
```

derived.php

```
<?php namespace MyQuestion\Configs;

use MyQuestion\Base;

class Settings extends BaseSetting
{
    private $a = 'value 1';
    private $b = 'value 2';
    private $c = "value 3";
}
```

index.php

```
$abc = new Settings();
$mySettings = $abc->GetValue('a');
```

I try to debug code. Something is broken in $this->setting. How can I do that? I have some settings file and I need to get values from them using a function. I don't want to define the same function in every setting file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scope of `private` $a to `protected` $a

or

you can

```
class Settings extends BaseSetting
{
 public function GetValue($setting)
    {
        return parent::getValue($setting)
    }
}
```

Without it when you will call `mySettings = $abc->GetValue('a');` it will call `BaseSetting::GetValue()` in context of `BaseSetting`. As `$a` is `private` it wont have access in `BaseSetting`. Either you need to change access modifier to lower like `public` or `protected` or you need call override `getValue()` and call return `parent::getValue($setting)` from there.

Comment: `return parent::GetValue($setting)` doesn't work if the properties modifier keep `private`.

Answer (score 0):

You could only access the private properties in the class in which the properties are declared. In you case, it's the class of `Settings`.

I don't know what you want exactly, but a work around might be

```
class Settings extends BaseSetting
{
    private $a = 'value 1';
    private $b = 'value 2';
    private $c = "value 3";

    public function __get($attr)
    {
        return $this->$attr;
    }
}
```

Then you could access the property by `$mySettings = $abc->a;`